# How to use Sublime text GotToAnything with selected text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Sublime text 2 GotToAnything was superb, I want to highlight a file name in my source code then I press the CTRL + P it  will auto select that file. I can do copy and paste. But sometime its not quiet right.

Is there any plugin to shortcut to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GotoSelection](https://github.com/FordAldrich/GotoSelection) I haven't used this, but it seems to be just what you want.

The description: *Small plugin for Sublime Text that pre-fills the Goto Anything overlay with the selected text or current word*.